# Recover feature names from pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, interpretation, black-box

I have adapted [a scikit-learn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) to fit my needs.

What it does is preprocess the columns according to their type: numerical data is scaled, but other data is transformed with OneHotEncoder.

Then, the pipeline joins the columns through a ColumnTransformer, and then feeds into a LogisticRegression.

**Is there an easy way to recover the feature names that correspond to the coefficients of the LogisticRegression** right before the end of the pipeline?

Or is manually keeping track of features the best idea? How would I go about that? My dataset has dozens of features, and after one-hot encoding, the linear model gets thousands.

I was able to get the OneHotEncoder's features like this: `clf.steps[0][1].transformers_[1][1].steps[1][1].get_feature_names()`

However, after concatenating them with the numeric features, I could not match them with coefficients in the LogisticRegression: `clf.steps[1][1].coef_`.

Comment: @Venkatachalam Yes it does. Thank you for linking it, I did not find it in a search: `[scikit-learn] feature names ColumnTransformer OneHotEncoder pipeline`, it seems SO search indexer does not split tokens by underscore.